# Computer logging off when I play fallout 4 (I expect it's because it's a heavy process)

Tags: windows, windows-10, gaming

Fallout 4 is pretty much the only heavy game I have on the PC and I don't really know how else to test the problem but after playing for about 40 minutes or so and it will log me out of my windows profile, I have looked for unusual processes in task manager and done a full system scan (spybot search and destroy)

I'm not sure what else it could be, any ideas?

It is possible this is in the wrong exchange because it's game related but I highly doubt it's a fallout 4 bug or anything - it wouldn't have access to the logging in/off process in windows right?

I am using windows 10

Comment: You logging out of your process likely means a service is crashing unrelated to Fallout 4

Comment: I guess but it ONLY happens when I play fallout 4.
I can be online for hours, watching netflix, playing online snooker, whatever. Then I play fallout 4 for 40 minutes or so and boom.

Comment: Is it possible that the fact the graphics card I'm using is barely good enough to run the game be causing it to crash and cause issues? idk why that would log me out though.

Comment: Did you look at the system error logs?  Most likely that is your best bet to find an answer.

Comment: its possible you are throwing a grenade (hold left alt) and accidentally hitting the windows key. win+L is "lock screen" which drops you to the sign-in screen. Unless you mean the computer is rebooting.

Comment: Is it possible, sure, just very unlikely

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before.  It is likely that your graphics card is getting too hot and is forcing a shut down or logout before you damage the card.

You can check to see if this is the case by downloading realtemp.  It will show you what temperatures your graphics card is reaching and can keep logs which you can later review.  If the card hits higher than 105 C you will immediately get shutdown or logged out.  I'm not sure what the fix would be aside from a new card but it would certainly help if you make sure that the card is free from dust and there is reasonable air flow assertions the card.  Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

May be driver problems, may be RAM problems, but it's probably Fallout 4. Fallout is a pretty buggy game unfortunately. I would give it few more days and let Bethesda push some more patches.

Answer (score -1):

If the problem is the graphics card overheating and you are using a tower computer you can get a tower computer case with fans that will cool down your graphics card.